# Can't boot to system

Tags: boot, network-manager, 21.04

I can't boot to ubuntu. It stucks at Networkmanager-dispatcher.service. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> just shows a black screen. I've tried to stop and disable this service, but nothing

And last thing I did on ubuntu was installed kubuntu desktop, but I removed it because of this stuck, but it didn't worked.

[image: Photo]

Comment: You apparently broke your system one or another way. The least technical approach will be a reinstall now.